# Two-port network parameter measurement using an LCR meter

Tags: impedance, measurement, s-parameters, lcr, admittance

I was wondering if it's possible to find the admittance parameters of a pi two-port network experimentally using an LCR meter.

For the network shown below, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I1\\
I2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
Y1 + Y2 & -Y1\\
-Y1 & Y1 + Y3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
V1\\
V2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So, if we short-circuit \$Y3\$ (\$V2 = 0\$), and connect LCR meter between nodes a and c, we measure admittance \$Y1+Y2\$, i.e. element \$y_{11}\$. Similarly, if we short-circuit \$Y2\$ (\$V1 = 0\$), and connect LCR meter between nodes b and c, we measure admittance \$Y1+Y3\$, i.e. element \$y_{22}\$.

However, I don't see how can we get \$Y1\$ since \$Y1 = \displaystyle-\frac{I2}{V1}\$(when \$V2 = 0\$), and I don't have access to measure either current or voltage but only impedance/admittance using the LCR meter.

Does anyone know if that's possible? If so, how do we proceed?
Also, can a network analyzer help with this task? Maybe through the use of S-parameters?

P.S: I'm working with a low frequency (100 Hz - 10 kHz).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I was wondering if it's possible to find the admittance parameters of a pi two-port network experimentally using an LCR meter.*

The answer is yes you can.

You can measure the impedance across each port with the other one shorted, this gives m1=Y1+Y2 and m2=Y1+Y3, then you can short a-b and measure across one port, this gives m3=Y2+Y3, and then Y1 = (m1+m2-m3)/2 and the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

> *I was wondering if it's possible to find the admittance parameters of
> a pi two-port network experimentally using an LCR meter*

Whether we talk about admittance parameters or impedance parameters; the problem is that you can find two of the four parameters by measuring impedance (or admittance) but, you can't find the other two. Consider the impedance parameters: -

[image]

- \$Z_{11}\$ can be found by simple measurement
- \$Z_{22}\$ can also be found by simple measurement

But you can't directly measure \$\frac{V_1}{I_2}\$ or \$\frac{V_2}{I_1}\$ so, you can't infer \$Z_{12}\$ or \$Z_{21}\$.

Whether its Y, Z or S parameters, two of the parameters relate to impedances or admittances and the other two parameters relate to the gain or transfer function of the 2-port network.

The answer is therefore no.

> *can a network analyzer help with this task? Maybe through the use of
> S-parameters?*

Some may and some may not. Read the brochure for the device.

Comment: So, we can't do that even with a network analyzer! Say, by measuring S-parameters then converting them to Y-parameters?

Comment: I cannot say what network analyser may or may not help here. I suspect some might and I expect some may not. I'm not an expert on network analysers @Likely. If you can extract S parameters and you know the reference impedance used then yes, you can convert to Y or Z parameters.